# Class to hash password using bcrypt

Tags: php, class, hash, password-protection, bcrypt

I have a basic knowledge about PHP but I want to learn how to use classes to make my program `OOP`, so I tried just a simple class that will generate a hash for the password and I'm using `bcrypt` for hashing.

So far the code i've written is this:

**PasswordHash.php**

```
class PasswordHash {
    public static function generate_bcrypt($user_password) {
        return $this->password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

`PasswordHash.php` is in the classes folder.

**index.php**

```
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    $password = 'mypassword';

    echo $hashed = PasswordHash::generate_bcrypt($password);
```

When I check if it is working, nothing happens. can someone help me with this? am I missing something on my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a start you're returning $this->password, when the public variable doesn't exist, and since you're calling the function statically, you can't use $this

Comment: Your just adding unnecessary work doing this. Especially when you can just call password_hash()

Comment: @LiamSorsby He wrote this is an attempt to learn how to use classes.

Comment: @arkascha yes i know that which there is nothing wrong with. I was simply just stating that in this particular case the simplest way would be to call the function directly

Comment: Also see Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To call it as an object**:

```
class PasswordHash {
        public function generate_bcrypt($user_password) {
            return password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
}

$password = 'password';
$passwordhash = new PasswordHash();
echo $passwordhash->generate_bcrypt($password);
```

**To call it using the static method**

```
class PasswordHash {
        public static function generate_bcrypt($user_password) {
            return password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
}

$password = 'password';
echo PasswordHash::generate_bcrypt($password);
```

You'll need to adapt this to fit the separation of your class files, but you can get the general idea from the examples.